# How to attach click event for elements rendering inside map function inside

Tags: spfx, typescript

I am using SPFx to create web part. I am generating checkboxes dynamically with map function. below is render method code

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IQuickSurveyProps> {
let styles: ICheckboxStyles = {
  root: {
    marginTop: '10px'
  }
};
let choicesArray: string[] = [];
let controlType: string = "";
return (
  <div className="">
    <div className="">
      {this.state.isError && <div><h3>Please give proper list name</h3></div>}
      {!this.state.isError &&
        <div>
          {
            this.state.listData.map(function (e, i) {
              if (e.Question_x0020_Type == "Choice") {
                controlType = "Radio";
              }
              else if (e.Question_x0020_Type == "Checkbox") {
                controlType = "Checkbox";
              }
              if (e.Options.indexOf(";") > 0) {
                choicesArray = e.Options.split(";");
              }
              else if (e.Options.indexOf("\n") > 0) {
                choicesArray = e.Options.split("\n");
              }
              return (
                <div>
                  {e.Title}
                  {
                    (choicesArray).map(function (item, key) {
                      return (
                        <div>
                          {(item.length != 0) ?
                            (<div><input type={controlType} 
                              name="chkbox"                                                              
                            value={item} /> 
                            <span>{item}</span></div>) : ""

                          }

                        </div>
                      )
                    })

                  }

                </div>
              )
            })

          }

          <div><button id="AlertMe" type="submit" onClick={this.submitDataToSP} >AlertMe</button></div>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

}

Now i want to attach click event for the the checkboxes which are generating inside map function. How I can do that? If i give like

```
<input type={controlType} name="chkbox" 
value={item} onClick={this.checkBoxClicked} />
```

is giving error as checkBoxClicked is undefined even though i have defined that method. But if I try to render any checkbox out of the map function and if i try to attach an event it is working fine similar to a button **AlertMe**

Comment: how about using `<input type={controlType} name="chkbox" 
value={item}  onClick={this.checkBoxClicked.bind(this, key)} />` ?

Comment: I have tried this as well. Not working.

Comment: ``.bind(this)`` would have to be chained to the function definition; that's ES**5** coding. 
In ES6 you can use arrow functions (as Waldek answers) this does the scope binding for you.

Comment: Good tutorial on everything ``this`` : http://2ality.com/2017/12/alternate-this.html

Answer (score 1):

In your `map` function, you're using `function(item,key)` which creates its own scope and makes `this` refer to the function rather than the component. You should be able to solve the issue by changing it to `(item, key) =>` which will retain the parent scope.